# Display icons/image instead of circle/path on map made with d3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, icons

I can successfully display some points on a openlayers basemap using d3.js however I want to actually display icons (at the moment maki png icons) instead of an svg point.

is it possible to load a png/jpg/svg image to a map using d3.js?

So far I can load the icon directly onto the svg but all the markers locate on the same spot so I think I'm having a problem converting the coordinates properly.

```
    var feature = svg.selectAll("path")
          .data(amenities.features)
          .enter()
          .append("svg:image")
          .attr("xlink:href", "maki/renders/post-18@2x.png")
          .attr("x", function(d, i) {return amenities.features[i].geometry.coordinates[0]})
          .attr("y", function(d, i) {return amenities.features[i].geometry.coordinates[1]})
          .attr("width", "20")
          .attr("height", "20")
          .attr("class", "amenity");
```

Previously I have been able to create an svg with image background inside it using a 'pattern' to show the image so that is also a possibility but I couldn't translate the code to use it with the geographic aspect of d3.

I know I'm writing the icons at the moment to the 'svg' div, so they don't transform correctly when I zoom in and out. I'm aiming to write the images to the 'g' div, as in have code like:

```
    var feature = g.selectAll("path")
```

but when I use this line, the elements appear on the document but the icons don't actually render on the map.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There a few issues here. First, I'm not sure you fully grasp how d3 selections works, as indicated by the fact that you are binding `amenities.features` to your selection and then accessing it for the `x` and `y` attributes via an index. See [How Selections Work](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/) for more details on this. In addition, you need to translate the geographic coordinates of the features to screen coordinates by passing them through your [geographic projection](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections) function. This should get you close:

```
// more projections: https://github.com/d3/d3-geo-projection/
var projection = d3.geoAlbers();

var amenities = svg.selectAll('.amenities')
     .data(amenities.features);

   amenities.enter().append('image');
    
   amenities
    .attr("class", "amenities")     
    .attr("xlink:href", "maki/renders/post-18@2x.png")
    // The data is already bound so use it instead of the index. Als, 
    // you need to translate geo coordinates to screen coordinates by 
    // passing them through your projection function.
    .attr("x", function(d,i) {return projection(d.geometry.coordinates)[0];})
    .attr("y", function(d,i) {return projection(d.geometry.coordinates)[1];})
    .attr("width", "20")
    .attr("height", "20")
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I appropriately used groups but I think the key is having the transform then translate thing in there.

So my example is http://bl.ocks.org/mpmckenna8/b87df1c44243aa1575cb.

But because I didn't use groups properly I don't know that the icons would handle zooming like you seem to want.  In my example I just append the images to the circles I've created.

```
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + projection(d.geometry.coordinates) + ")"; })
  .attr('opacity',.3)
  .attr('fill', '#fad959')
```